# How to merge overlapping rectangle in OpenCV ? (Python)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm using two haarcascade algorythm (frontal and profil) at the same time to improve the face detection.

**I've found that I need to use `cv2.GroupRectangles(rectList, groupThreshold)` but it's not working.** The program returns me this :

> The true value of a array with more than one element is ambigious. Use
>   a.any() or a.all()

How can i integrate it into my code ?

```
import cv2

    image=cv2.imread("/home/pi/Downloads/test.jpg")
    face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("Path of first algorithm")
    profil_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("Path of second algorithm")

    gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.06, 5)
    profil=profil_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)
    cv2.groupRectangles(face and profil, 2)

    print("I've found "+str(len(face)+len(profil))+ " face(s)")

    for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    for (x,y,w,h) in profil:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Download/result.jpg", image)
```

**Thank you in advance, and have a nice day :)**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Why do you say your code isn't working?  If you see an error message, please edit your question to include the error.

Comment: Thank you ! The normal code is working, but when i add `cv2.GroupRectangles(face and profil, 2)`, the program return me that "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous".

Comment: @TheSanchezRick Edit your code in the question and add the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: I've done it, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.groupRectangles()` expects a `list` to be passed as a parameter.

In your case `face` and `profil` are of `array` type. So when you do `and` operation it will certainly throw the error mentioned. Here is the fix:

Append both the arrays column-wise:

```
combined_array = np.append(face, profil, axis = 0)
```

Convert this array to a list:

```
combined_list = combined_array.tolist()
```

Now pass this list to `cv2.GroupRectangles()`:

```
result = cv2.groupRectangles(combined_list, groupThreshold)
```

Upon inspecting `result`, it is actually a `tuple` containing two values:

- an array of the rectangle coordinates
- the weight for the rectangle (meaning how likely it is to be a grouped rectangle)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :D I've follow your instruction and everything work normally... but it didn't change the overlapping rectangle.

Comment: @TheSanchezRick You have to use the coordinates from `result[0]`.

Comment: You're right, that make sense ! I've replace like this `print("I've found "+str(len(result))+" face"` and `for (x,y,w,h) in result[0]` and delete the second one but nothing is draw on the picture. Have I made a mistake ? He also indicate me that i've only 2 faces found on a picture with 5 faces (normally detect)